Is there any erlang BEAM decompiler?
Is there any solution to manipulate (or decompile and recompile agian) an erlang .beam file that has no_abstarct_code ?

:beam_lib.chunks("myfile.beam",[:abstract_code]) doesn't work.
famous beam_lib wrapper https://github.com/hrzndhrn/beam_file doesn't work.

I tried to work with beam_lib and beam_file, but I failed.

Could you please share the BEAM file and elaborate on what “does not work” mean? Failing how exactly? Saying what?
